# Can I donate investment income to charity without getting taxed

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, dividends, charity

I'm wondering if I can donate stock cash dividends or bond interests to charities and make the donations tax deductible?

Update: sorry I think I phrased my question poorly. What I really wanted to know was whether I could receive a dividend or interest, not get taxed, donate it and get a tax deduction.

Comment: This double dipping applies only to unrealized capital gains, not to dividends or interest -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

These are really two different things. You can't "combine" them.

You have income from stock cash dividends or bond interests. You need to pay income tax on these and then the money is "free & clear" yours and you can do with it whatever you want.

You can donate any of your money to charity. It makes no difference where it comes from. The donation is tax deductible but the deduction only makes a difference in how much taxes you pay, if you itemize: i.e. the sum of your itemized deductions is larger then the standard deduction

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question more broadly: If you have taxable investments and want to make donations, consider directly donating securities (rather than income or proceeds from them) if you have unrealized capital gains. This [allows](https://www.forbes.com/sites/brucebrumberg/2018/11/26/making-charitable-donations-of-stock-instead-of-cash-after-tax-reform/) you to deduct the current market value of the donation (if you itemize) *and* avoid paying capital gains tax.